# Is is possible to get Excel to insert an absolute reference when clicking on cells to build a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If you build a formula by clicking on a cell to insert its address into the formula, is there a way of making this reference absolute rather than relative?

I've been using Excel for many years but never come across a way of doing this.  I've tried the obvious SHIFT+ click, CTRL+click and ALT+click.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Click the cell and then hit F4.  As you keep hitting F4, it will cycle through various level of absolute.

Example:

- Click the cell A1, type '=', then click the cell B1.
- Hit F4.  The reference to B1 becomes $B$1.
- Hit F4 again.  The reference becomes B$1.
- Hit F4 again.  The reference becomes $B1.
- Hit F4 again.  The reference returns to B1.

Comment: Also answered in: http://superuser.com/questions/18945/useful-excel-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @pelms - the link you provided does not exist anymore. Any idea where was the question moved to?

Comment: @ysap It probably wasn't kept, IIRC the link was a bit of a laundry list which I think the network now tries to discourage.

Answer (score 5):

I've just been through a similar issue where I needed to do this for a large number of cells ad-hoc

And this code saved my sanity :)

```
Sub selectedToAbsolute()
 Dim c As Variant
    For Each c In Selection
        c.Value = Application.ConvertFormula(c.Formula, xlA1, , xlAbsolute)
    Next c
End Sub

Sub selectedToRelative()
 Dim c As Variant
    For Each c In Selection
        c.Value = Application.ConvertFormula(c.Formula, xlA1, , xlRelative, c)
    Next c
End Sub
```